# What third-party services/libraries exist for user registration forms?

Tags: php, wordpress, registration

I'm looking for any existing services/libraries `(PHP preferrably)` that I can implement into my existing solution (wordpress/symfony) to handle user registration (personal information like name, address, e-mail etc.)

What options exist today, or will I have to pull out my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has wordpress not already got a register option for users? Quick google search:

http://www.cozmoslabs.com/2010/05/31/wordpress-user-registration-template-and-custom-user-profile-fields/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with [sfGuard](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin) ..?